# ink!: Initializing custom structure

Tags: ink, storage

I have an auxiliary struct:

```rust
#[derive(SpreadAllocate, SpreadLayout)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(TypeInfo, ink_storage::traits::StorageLayout))]
pub struct MerkleTree<const LEAVES: u32> {
    nodes: Mapping<u32, Hash>,
    next_free_leaf: u32,
}

/// The only way of constructing `MerkleTree`.
impl<const LEAVES: u32> Default for MerkleTree<LEAVES> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        if !LEAVES.is_power_of_two() {
            panic!("Please have 2^n leaves")
        }

        Self {
            nodes: Mapping::default(),
            next_free_leaf: LEAVES,
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it in my contract:

```rust
#[ink(storage)]
#[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
pub struct Contract {
    tree: MerkleTree<1024>,
}
```

The contract has a single constructor:

```rust
impl Contract {
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|blender: &mut Self|{})
    }
...
}
```

I observe that my struct (`tree` field is not initialized properly) - `next_free_leaf` is set to `0` (which is `Default::default()` for `u32`). Thus my constructor couldn't have been called. I suppose that the mapping inside this struct might not have been initialized properly. How should I initialize such structs properly?

I'm working with ink 3.4.0 (I have to).

Comment: for custom struct you have to implement `SpreadLayout ` like in the [`official docs`](https://use.ink/4.0.0-alpha.1/datastructures/custom-datastructure) you can go through it

Comment: isn't it enough that I have already derived it?

Comment: Can you tell me how did you observe that `tree` field is not initilized properly? I have modified your constructor [`like this`](https://gist.github.com/ink-playground-gists/d9a6046d0b9909e4d3459ea13f562115) it builds.

Comment: Well, I have been warned by docs: https://use.ink/4.0.0-alpha.1/datastructures/mapping/#initializing-a-mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here that the `Test` value passed to `initialize_contract` is initialized with `SpreadAllocate::allocate_spread`. You are expecting that it would be initialized using your `Default` implementation. This is why you need to manually override this value in `initialize_contract` to make it work as expected.

This behaviour is really confusing and should have never made it into ink!. This is why we got rid of `SpreadAllocate` and `initialize_contract` in ink!4.

Answer (score 2):

As a followup, there's a smaller version of the contract that suffers from the same problems:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod test {
    use ink_storage::traits::{SpreadAllocate, SpreadLayout};

    #[derive(Debug, SpreadAllocate, SpreadLayout)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo, ink_storage::traits::StorageLayout))]
    pub struct Inner {
        value: u32,
    }

    impl Default for Inner {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Inner {
                value: 100
            }
        }
    }

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Test {
        inner: Inner,
    }

    impl Test {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_: &mut Test| {

            })
        }
        
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get(&self) -> u32 {
            self.inner.value
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::test::Test;

    use super::*;

    #[ink::test]
    fn default_works() {
        let t = Test::new();
        assert_eq!(t.get(), 100)
    }

}
```

"Fortunately", the unit test fails as expected - the value returned from `get()` call is not 100 (as set in the default constructor) but 0.

Comment: you can update your constructor like this: `Self {inner: Default::default()}` and it works

Comment: but this won't work if `Self` has e.g. `Mapping` field as well, right? we would have to use `ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract` then

Comment: I don't think so because Mapping can be initialize by `Mapping::default()` and they have excluded in updated version as [you can view](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/gn/mapping-take-tests/examples/mappings/lib.rs) in this example

Comment: then it is in opposite to https://use.ink/4.0.0-alpha.1/datastructures/mapping/#initializing-a-mapping

Comment: As `Mapping` is in `storage` then `ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract` must be included inside constructor but [In this example](https://gist.github.com/ink-playground-gists/20784008ec376f27dae9fa198a3a892d), I seperated Mapping to different struct and there is no requirement of `ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract` in constructor

Comment: and [this example is](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/gn/mapping-take-tests/examples/mappings/lib.rs) based on ink!  version `4.0.0-alpha.3`  so in the future we just need to use `Mapping::default()`

Comment: If `initialize_contract` is not required it should be enforced by the compiler. Otherwise it's like giving people a gun without giving them a warning. I don't consider the explanation on `Mapping` sufficient.